# Percentage and Mean

Tags: percentages

Okay, I wanna Calculate my grade in a class.Formative is worth 35% of the grade, Summative is 55% and Final exam is 10%. For formative, I have 86.3%. For summative, I have 68%. The final exam has not been take and is therefore 0/0. What is my overall grade in the class?

Comment: Dear Sir,your average is $67.605%$. I just did $35*86.3 + 68*55 + 0*10$. I don't understand why you would post such an elementary question, though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you mean by your current overall grade. Treating the whole grade as $100$ marks, with $35$ marks available for Formative, $55$ for Summative, and $10$ for the Final exam, you currently have $86.3$% of the $35$ marks available for Formative and $68$% of the $55$ available for Summative, for a total of

$$0.863\cdot35+0.68\cdot55=30.205+37.4=67.605$$

out of the $90$ marks available so far. That’s a score of

$$\frac{67.605}{90}\cdot100=75.11\overline6\%\;.$$

- If you do approximately equally well on the final, you’ll end up with about $75$ out of $100$ marks, or an overall grade of about $75$%.
- If you score nothing on the final, you’ll end up with $67.605$ marks out of $100$, or an overall grade of $67.605$%.
- And if you score $100$% on the final, you’ll end up with $67.605+10=77.605$ marks out of $100$, or an overall grade of $77.605$%.